# Understand this TX (attack on pancakeswap)

Tags: transactions, uniswap, attacks, binance-smart-chain

Can someone help me understand how this attack works?

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6781925966f5236c057d425e00378e4d4b8685c49eae9ddf48229ebcba682463

He basically SWAPS 0.000000001 BNB for some otkens, and then somehow swaps more tokens that he got for > 1.71 BNB.

Comment: Why do you say that it's an attack? The token seems to have been bough for 2 Eth about 2 minutes earlier in another transaction. https://bscscan.com/tx/0x952c5296c3a9378c1080562e78fc1a168e7571143a753cdecb05c819ab5ad02e